# Can static methods that return a value throw an exception?

Tags: java

I have a static method that returns a String, but in the event that the string that is passed in does not match one of several words, I want to throw an exception. The code below is just a sample of what I am trying to do, but I keep getting "non static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context" message on the line where I throw the exception. Basically, the return value from getMsg has to be valid, or the program cannot proceed, so I need a way to catch this.

```
public static String getMsg(String input) throws UnknownInputException{
      if (input.equals("A")){
           return "key for A";
      }
      throw new UnknownInputException("Some Message");
      return "unknownInput";
```

Comment: this code doesn't match the error message you're posting. You need to post the actual error message itself and let us know which line is causing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact, that `UnknownInputException` is probably a nested class, and if you instantiate it with the `new` operator, as a nested class, it should have access to a "parent" object - which doesn't exist since the class was instantiated in a static context. For more information about this, see [Static method returning inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058974/static-method-returning-inner-class).

A possible solution would be to declare `UnknownInputException` as `static` like this:

```
private static class UnknownInputException extends Exception { ... }
```

Of course, you won't be able to access any instance (non-static) methods and/or fields from this class, but that might not be an issue in your case (especially in case of an Exception class).

Also, `return`ing value after the `throw` line is unnecessary, as execution will never reach that line.

Answer (score 2):

The variable *this* is not noted in the given example code, so it can not cause an error.

The code `return "unknownInput";` is redundant since never executed.

There must be another static method in which `this` is used, that causes the error.

Comment: I see your point about the return value, but doesn't a method that returns a String have to return a value??

Comment: Not if it throws an Exception or Error.

Comment: Ok. Nowhere in my method am I using the word 'this', so I dont know why I am getting that compile error.

Comment: I guess I forgot to make the UnknownInputException class static, it is an inner class. Works now :-)

Answer (score 2):

The UnknownInputException is an inner class. Once I made it static, the code compiled fine. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: It is not normal practice to create inner exception classes in Java.  Indeed, I can't recall seeing a well-known API that does this.  Consider making it a top-level class.

Answer (score 0):

Its perfectly legal in java to throw exceptions from static methods.
However the code you've presented here can't be even compiled :)
So provide all the code.

The error you get here just says that you're using non static data fields defined on class from the static method.
The static method doesn't belong to any instance, but the data field does...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `return "unknownInput";` line will never be executed. Is it not showing a dead code warning there ?

And your method doesn't have any 'this' reference, are you sure it complains about this method ?